# What is the best way to identify the updater of an observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Given any knockout example, **I want to be able to identify the source of an observable update**.

Consider for example this simple code:

HTML

```
<input type='text' data-bind='value: someValue' />
<span data-bind='text: someValue'></span>
<button data-bind='click: updateValue'>Update</button>
```

js

```
var vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.someValue = ko.observable('random value');
    this.updateValue = function () {
        self.someValue('random value ' + Math.round(Math.random()*10));
    }
}

var vmi = new vm();

vmi.someValue('other random value');

ko.applyBindings(vmi);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/5W9p5/)**

I want to know if `someValue`was last updated via the input tag, the button, or via code.

What do you think would be **the best way** to do so? (extender, custom binding handler, ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create separate "writable computed observables" for each of those things to modify.  See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#writeable_computed_observables.  In your `write` methods for each of these, you can handle differentiation/coordination/syncing between them as appropriate.  There might be a better solution though if you described your actual scenario.

Comment: I have a real case behind this but I was curious to get a generic solution

Comment: I'm sure you do :)  My point is that by giving us a more concrete scenario, we might be able to recommend a better approach.  From a conceptual architecture perspective, viewmodels shouldn't know or care what view is making changes to them so your root problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: Isn't this example concrete enough? What you say about viewmodels is true I guess. In my real case scenario, I want to know if the observable's value comes from the user through the interface, or if it was updated from code

Comment: @GôTô Robert Levy is absolutely correct in his approach - out of the box you should use a computed write, unless there is a more complex situation or you are using additional utilities on top of Knockout.  Example - http://jsfiddle.net/5W9p5/1/ - will alert you user vs function input

Comment: Thanks @PWKad, that's already what I did following Robert Levy. I wanted to know my options, maybe avoid adding a new observable.